# Find data frame row in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 different dataframes, with equal columns.
I'd like to find the index of the element `i` from `dataframe1` in `dataframe2`.

Something like this:

```
dataframe1.iloc[i] = ...

for i, r in dataframe2.iterrows():
    if r == dataframe1.iloc[i]:
        print(i)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a potential solution:

```py
>>> df1
   A  B  C  D
0  1  0  0  0
1  0  1  0  0
2  0  0  1  0
3  0  0  0  1

>>> df2
   A  B  C  D
0  0  0  1  0
1  1  0  0  0
2  0  0  1  0
3  0  0  0  1

>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.where((df1 == df2).all(axis=1))[0]
array([2, 3])
```

NumPy is a dependency of Pandas so you don't need to install any other package.

**Explanation**:

```py
>>> df1 == df2  # compare all elements of df1 to df2
       A      B      C     D
0  False   True  False  True
1  False  False   True  True
2   True   True   True  True
3   True   True   True  True

>>> (df1 == df2).all(axis=1)  # True if all elements in row (axis=1) are True
0    False
1    False
2     True
3     True
dtype: bool

>>> np.where((df1 == df2).all(axis=1))  # the indices where the element is True
(array([2, 3]),)

>>> np.where((df1 == df2).all(axis=1))[0]  # the first element of the tuple from np.where
array([2, 3])
```